# FTP upload fails to azure using PSFTP Powershell Module

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using a powershell module provided by microsoft called PSFTP. When the script runs on any developer Windows 10 powershell it works fine, but on the build server it fails with an error message (530) Not logged in. Why might it be failing with that message on Windows Server 2016 only? It's the same script with same credentials.

PSFTP source is here https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb

```
$username = "azureusername"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "azurepassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
$ftpserver = "ftp://*****ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net"
$fileToDelete = "/site/wwwroot/bin"
Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $cred -Server $ftpserver -Session MyFTPSession -UsePassive
$Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MyFTPSession
Remove-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $fileToDelete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I test in my Windows Server 2016, if I use the username and password that download from Portal `Get publish profile`. I get the same error log with you.

[image]

I set the username and password on Azure Portal.
[image]

It works for me fine.

[image]

Comment: No luck, using msdeploy.exe instead. I would warn anyone away from using PSFTP these scripts are not suitable for continuous integration.